# Python String Query

Tags: python, twitter, bots

I recently made a Twitter-bot that takes a specified .txt file and tweets it out, line by line. A lot of the features I built into the program to troubleshoot some formatting issues actually allows the program to work with pretty much any text file.

I would like build in a feature where I can "import" a .txt file to use.

I put that in quotes because the program runs in the command line at them moment.

I figured there are two ways I can tackle this problem but need some guidance on each:

A) I begin the program with a prompt asking which file the user want to use. This is stored as a string (lets say variable string) and the code looks like this-

```
file = open(string,'r')
```

There are two main issues with. The first is I'm unsure how to keep the program from crashing if the program specified is misspelled or does not exist. The second is that it won't mesh with future development (eventually I'd like to build app functionality around this program)

B) Somehow specify the desired file somehow in the command line. While the program will still occasionally crash, it isn't as inconvenient to the user. Also, this would lend itself to future development, as it'll be easier to pass a value in through the command line than an internal prompt.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding A), you may want to investigate

```
try:
    with open(fname) as f:
        blah = f.read()
except Exception as ex:
    # handle error
```

and for B) you can, e.g.

```
import sys
fname = sys.argv[1]
```

You could also combine the both to make sure that the user has passed an argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import sys

def tweet_me(text):
    # your bot goes here
    print text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        fname = sys.argv[1]
        with open(fname) as f:
            blah = f.read()
        tweet_me(blah)
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex
        print "Please call this as %s <name-of-textfile>" % sys.argv[0]
```

Just in case someone wonders about the `# encoding: utf-8` line. This allows the source code to contain `utf-8` characters. Otherwise only ASCII is allowed, which would be ok for this script. So the line is not necessary. I was, however, testing the script on itself (`python x.py x.py`) and, as a little test, added a `utf-8` comment (`# ä`). In real life, you will have to care a lot more for character encoding of your input...

Beware, however, that just catching any `Exception` that may arise from the whole program is not considered good coding style. While Python encourages to assume the best and `try` it, it might be wise to catch expectable errors right where they happen. For example , accessing a file which does not exist will raise an `IOError`. You may end up with something like:

```
    except IndexError as ex:
        print "Syntax: %s <text-file>" % sys.argv[0]
    except IOError as ex:
        print "Please provide an existing (and accessible) text-file."
    except Exception as ex:
        print "uncaught Exception:", type(ex)
```

Comment: except Exception is pretty bad, I would specify what exception will happen and except it. (Not on PC so cant test, something like FileError)

Comment: it was meant to introduce OP to a new concept and encourage own resaerch.

Comment: Then I would mention that it's bad style in the answer, and maybe link to some article regarding types of exceptions

Comment: This is true. I will update the answer accordingly so that it will be more helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question, exception handling is the way to go . Though for the second part you can also use a module called argparse.

```
import argparse

# creating command line argument with the name file_name   
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("file_name", help="Enter file name")
args = parser.parse_args()
# reading the file
with open(args.file_name,'r') as f:
    file = f.read()
```

You can read more about the argparse module on its documentation page.